# angular2 aot compile. What does implicitly has an 'any' type mean and how to correct it?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

TypeScript compile

```
tsc -w -p  tsconfig-aot.json
```

get many error

app/admin/appeals_messages/appeals_messages.components.ts(22,5): error TS7008: Member 'userInfo' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/admin/appeals_messages/appeals_messages.components.ts(33,5): error TS7008: Member 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type.
app/admin/appeals_messages/appeals_messages.components.ts(64,40): error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Params'.
app/admin/appeals_messages/appeals_messages.components.ts(70,17): error TS7006: Parameter 'res' implicitly has an 'any' type.

.....

Why arise it's error? TypeScript is backward compatible with js language and in theory must skip its error because i write its code as js-code?
Mabe have a way to collect it with its error, because tsc with out aot collect app and it work?

Help, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors says nothing else than that the variable has no type declared. So Typescript is assuming that this is an "any" type which is why its "implicitly".

In your **tsConfig.json** is a line where you can configure the behaviour:

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

But it would be better to give this variable a type or declare it as "any". Then its explicitly set and the error should be gone.

Comment: thankou for answer, but aot compiling without angular-cli  is pain.

Comment: It is installing two packages and run a command :-) Anyway: Did my answer help you?